# how Yahoo, New-York Times submit read artice to facebook open graph not violate facebook policies

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I just submitted my app with open graph about reading news to Facebook, still waiting for approving.

I following guide here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/

But I very confused about which is the best way to submit when visitor read an article.

1. Create a button/link at the end of article, let user submit if he want to 
   (I am sure not many people give time to do this)
2. Create action `onclick` of every next, back, other article links, so when user read other articles, the submit will start (have hard code to make sure submit successful before user go to other article's links)
3. Using timeout function eg 30 seconds to auto submit if user reading that article. (I'm not sure this is violate Facebook policies or not)
4. Other way around? Please give me advice

I did check the Yahoo News, New-York Times and still don't understand how they submit article every time user read it. Anyone could point me out will very helpful.

Thanks in advance

---

**Notice UPDATE.** I'm not use this to spam anyone, that why I am asking here how Yahoo, New-York Times did it.
Actually today after investigated I found the way they use. They work with Facebook guild-line. But I still working out on script for archive that. Look at my question for relating issue

Answer (score 0):

If you go for ANY auto-submit each time an article is ready, your users would leave you in droves. Check out this article. http://allfacebook.com/social-readers-down_b88125

Facebook also clearly state you should offer a prompt unless there is some reason why you can't do it (such as you're posting to the user's wall based on another action when the user is not in front of the computer, e.g. User B "likes" user A's post, so this gets posted ot User A's wall when they are not there).

Your best course of action would be to:
a) Offer a prompt.
b) Offer a config option, offering to post each time if the user wants it
c) If you want to "push" a little bit, probably no harm in the FIRST post being an auto-post (although you also need to aske permissions for this, and that may put users off). Then go for prompts.

Comment: Yep i totally agree ... When i ask for authosized the app I also clear that the article user readed will post to time line... 

But actualy user normal read about 5-6 articles every time they visite the web .. I dont want auto post too much .. that like spamming and even hurt the resouce of my server every time facebock scrap the articles..

That why I asking for solution how the Yahoo , NYT .. other news website what they are doing the best to post time line and not annoying people, also in auto..